# Mechanism of toluene oxidation with CrO3

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organic-oxidation

What is the mechanism for the following oxidation of toluene with $\ce{CrO3}$ in acetic anhydride?

> Use of chromic oxide ($\ce{CrO3}$): Toluene or substituted toluene is converted to benzylidene diacetate on treating with chromic oxide in acetic anhydride. The benzylidene diacetate can be hydrloyzed to corresponding benzaldehyde with aqueuous acid.

[image]

Comment: This appears to be the Étard reaction, which proceeds via a 2,3 Sigmatropic rearrangment.  You can read about it [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Étard_reaction).

Comment: In etard reaction Chromylchloride is used and if it were like etard reaction then methyl of toluene will not get disubsituted.

Comment: I don't see why CrO2Cl2 would behave any differently than chromic oxide.  Can you explain why you would expect a different outcome?

Comment: Please see this http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58381/etard-reaction-chromium-complex

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tard_reaction

Comment: wikipedia mechanism is based on papers of 1950-60s .. pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ic200877f this is a recent mechanism proposed

Comment: What is the evidence that the Etard reaction is [2,3]-sigmatropic rearrangement? Read this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/140039/%c3%89tard-reaction-of-ethylbenzene/140153#140153

Answer (score 5):

The following mechanism is based on the findings made in *The Mechanism of the Etard Reaction<sup>[[1]](https://doi.org/10.1016/s0040-4020(01)98572-2)</sup>*.

---

[image: Etard like reaction]

---

**Reference:**

<sup>[(1)](https://doi.org/10.1016/s0040-4020(01)98572-2) Necsoiu, I.; Balaban, A. T.; Pascaru, I.; Sliam, E.; Elian, M.; Nenitzescu, C. D. The Mechanism of the Etard Reaction. *Tetrahedron* **1963**, *19* (7), 1133–1142.</sup>