# Mechanism for an Étard reaction (chromium complex)

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, transition-metals

In the following reaction, a chromium complex is formed during the Étard reaction:

[image]

I have the following questions:

1. How is this complex formed?
2. How does its hydrolysis take place? (What's the mechanism?)

Wikipedia gives a different mechanism for the same reaction. I am in doubt which is correct?
[image]

---

@Jan is this the correct mechanism?

[image]

Comment: Wikipedia’s mechanism is basically the same.

Comment: How ? There is disubstitution in book and mono substitution on Wikipedia. I am unable to figure out how after disubstitution hydrolysis takes place? I understand hydrolysis when monosubstituted.

Comment: Ooooh, now I see it, the two escaped me. But you can think of $\mathrm{S_N2}$ type attack of a water molecule to chromium, displacement of one alcoholate which then rearranges to displace the second one. I’m not in a place where I can draw compounds now though (and won’t be until in a few days).

Comment: 1) http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ic200877f . The proposed mechanism is radical, though it is yet to be proven experimentally. However, the mixture of products is in agreement with this proposal. 2) The mechanism would be extremely hard to prove, but I suppose it should be an addition/dissociation type mechanism, similar to nucleophilic substitution at $sp^2$  carbon atoms.

Comment: @Jan I am uploading the picture of hydrolysis please check it in the answers column.

Comment: Pretty much what I would assume, yes.

Comment: The ene reaction mechanism for the Etard reaction is questionable given this data. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/140039/%c3%89tard-reaction-of-ethylbenzene

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mechanism of toluene oxidation with CrO3](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58371/mechanism-of-toluene-oxidation-with-cro3)