# Mechanism of Etard reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

According to Wikipedia Etard reaction proceed via a ene reaction with chromyl chloride forming a Etard complex(Chromium complex) which is then decomposed by a [2,3] sigmatropic shift to give aldehyde.

[image]

But the reaction given in my textbook is as follows,
[image]

Mechanism of this reaction suggested by Wikipedia does not create the intermediate of this reaction given in my textbook.The Chromium complex is further hydrolysed to give benzaldehyde.

Some sources which I referred suggest that Etard reaction proceed via a radical mechanism.
https://pubs.acs.org/doi/suppl/10.1021/ic200877f/suppl_file/ic200877f_si_001.pdf

What is the correct mechanism of this reaction?Is the Chromium complex given in my textbook correct?

Comment: Exact copy of- https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58381/mechanism-for-an-%c3%89tard-reaction-chromium-complex

Comment: Which textbook are you using?

Comment: The answer is within the comments

Comment: Organic chemist can imagine a lot of $wrong$ things with their imaginary arrow pushing constructs. It is not necessary that if the arrows pushing story makes some sense like a typical movie, then it is real story. *Only an experiment* can draw a reasonable conclusion. Don't be impressed with DFTs or fancy names. Someone jokingly said in a meeting that hardcore theoreticians cannot distinguish between a cow and methane.  I am not an organic chemist, but as a student I wasted a lot of time in believing in those arrow pushing mechanisms and thinking that all reaction mechanisms were known.

Comment: Look for original papers from the oldest first. A lot of papers appear from 1960s and indeed it is clear that it is a very complex reaction. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0040402001985722