# Étard Reaction of Ethylbenzene

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

What is the major product when the following compound undergoes Étard reaction?

[image]

Is it acetophenone or a terminal aldehyde.
The mechanism discussed in [Mechanism for an Étard reaction (chromium complex)](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/58381/63955) does not give any conclusive prediction.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58381/mechanism-for-an-%c3%89tard-reaction-chromium-complex?noredirect=1&lq=1 (you've already mentioned) https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58371/mechanism-of-toluene-oxidation-with-cro3?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/127304/mechanism-of-etard-reaction?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Apparently the Etard reaction of ethylbenzene is not as simple as with toluene. This information is from Chem. Absts. "The Etard complex of ethylbenzene (I) was prepd. in CCl4 at 0°.  Decompn. of the Etard complex of I by water yielded phenylacetaldehyde (II) and acetophenone (III) in equal proportions, along with styrene and BzH. Revue Roumaine de Chimie, 1967, 12, 1495-1501.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A mechanism has been proposed herein for the Étard oxidation of ethylbenzene that parallels the proposed oxidation of toluene with chromyl chloride (CrO2Cl2) as a [2,3]-sigmatropic rearrangement that is found on Wikipedia.<sup>[1]</sup> While such a mechanism is a convenient way to rationalize the formation of benzaldehyde, it does not consider the “Étard complex” that has a composition, in most cases, of RH/2CrO<sub>2</sub>Cl<sub>2</sub> or greater proportion of CrO<sub>2</sub>Cl<sub>2</sub>.<sup>[2]</sup>
This mechanism is incompatible with the Étard oxidation of n-propylbenzene and ethylbenzene, both of which studies are cited on Wikipedia. The products derived from these higher homologs reveal both α- and β-
carbon oxidation.
Nenitzescu and co-workers<sup>[3]</sup> demonstrated that the Étard oxidation of ethylbenzene affords acetophenone and phenylacetaldehyde, which answers the OP’s question.  The following summary is from Chemical Abstracts:

> "The Etard complex of ethylbenzene (I) was prepd. in CCl4 at 0°. Decompn. of the Etard complex of I by water yielded phenylacetaldehyde (II) and acetophenone (III) in equal proportions, along with styrene and BzH.”<sup>[3]</sup>

That n-propylbenzene **1a** affords benzyl methyl ketone **2a** and propiophenone **3** has been known since 1890.<sup>[4]</sup> Wiberg, et al.<sup>[5]</sup> explored the mechanism of this reaction using n-propyl-β-d<sub>2</sub>-benzene **1b**. Oxidation of **1b** provided benzyl methyl ketone **2b** containing 60% deuterium at the α-position, which indicated a rearrangement was occurring. The presence of α-chloro-n-propylbenzene **5** was also observed. These investigators demonstrated that oxidation of propenylbenzene **4** gave rise to benzyl methyl ketone **2a**. 
The evidence points to either a radical process<sup>[5,6]</sup> or one that invokes hydride transfer,<sup>[2]</sup> i.e., cationic, at the benzylic carbon. There is little evidence, if any, for a [2,3]-sigmatropic rearrangement in this reaction. If there is, please apprise me.

[image]

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89tard_reaction
2. I. Necsoiu, A. T. Balaban, I. Pascaru, E. Sliam, M. Eliam, C. D. Nenitzescu, *Tetrahedron*, **1963**, *19*, 1133.
3. C. N. Rentea, M. Rentea, I. Necsoiu and D. Nenitzescu,  *Revue Roumaine de Chimie*, **1967**, *12*, 1495.
4. W. v. Miller and G. Rhode, *Chemische Berichte*, **1890**, *23*, 1070.
5. K. B. Wiberg, B. Marshall and G. Foster, *Tetrahedron Letters*, **1962**, 345.
6. M. Drees and T. Strassner, *Inorg. Chem.*, **2011**, *50*, 5833.

Answer (score 5):

Ethylbenzene yields acetophenone when it undergoes Étard reaction.

The mechanism is as follows:

[image: Étard reaction]
[image: Étard reaction]