# Etard's reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, redox, carbonyl-compounds

My textbook says the following on Etard's reaction:

[image]

Now, if the alkyl group attached to benzene is an unsymmetrical or branched alkyl group, such as this:
[image]

What will be the reaction product(s)? Which terminal carbon will be oxidised to a carbonyl carbon?

Comment: I don't know which book you used to get that information for ethyl benzene, but this is wrong. See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/140039/%C3%89tard-reaction-of-ethylbenzene (related) It is 1 of the products, but by no means major. Higher alkanes attached further undergo several different rearrangements giving chloride aldehyde and ketone isomers hence this reaction is only preferred for toluene

Comment: You'll get a mixture